# Creating an iso of a RHEL instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel, rhel7

I have an amazon ec2 instance with RHEL 7.3 on it. I would like to convert this into an iso so that I can migrate it wherever I want. What are the best tools to create an iso of a virtual machine. Or how do I clone/backup this VM so that I can restore it anywhere I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with VM and AWS programatically via [AWS CLI commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/).

You want to get familiar with **import-task** and **export-task** commands.

The best place to start is by reading an official AWS guides for:

- [Exporting an Instance as a VM Using VM Import/Export](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html)
- [Importing a VM as an Image Using VM Import/Export](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html)

The key information you need to pick up from the guide is this quote:

> "You can't export an instance from Amazon EC2 unless you previously
>   imported it into Amazon EC2 from another virtualization environment."

Yes, there are solutions, one of them linked by @Nicholas Smith. That being said, if you go the unofficial route you might end up in a dark alley where help might not be available. I highly recommend and warn here to not proceed with trying to clone EC2 into VM at this point. You will spend a lot of time with a huge risk factor for future.

For you to be able to achieve what you want, you need to create a RHEL VM using any VM software, you need to load this VM into AWS and then you will be able to work with VM in AWS making any necessary changes and export again for local or transportation needs.

As you are running a widely-used Linux distribution - RHEL, you can attempt to recreate your EC2 environment manually by launching a VM that runs the same kernel version along with the same package versions. From there, you can tarball what files you need from your production instance and copy them over to your on-premise site by using SCP/SFTP.

Just get your RHEL environment into VM locally and import to AWS and you set.

Answer (score 0):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) provides functionality to create images. Generated images can be converted to ISO files.

Comment: I want to perform this programatically. So I am looking from some option to clone a VM through command line.

Comment: Clonezilla has a command line interface as well, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be something that Amazon promote as a service however the `aws cli` tools have an `ec2-unbundle` command for extracting from an AMI. There's a guide [here](https://preda.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/downloading-an-amazon-ec2-ami-to-local-drive/) on how to download and run an EC2 AMI locally by using it.

Caveat is it appears the `ec2-unbundle` command currently only works on Linux and not OS X or Windows.

Comment: This mentions use of vmware to convert into iso. Can't we do without it?

Comment: From reading what they're doing to get it to a bootable stage it looks like you have to go through it to get a workable ISO.